# Quarkus with keycloak `permit` for path containing path parameter does not work

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

I am trying to use quarkus with keycloak and using `quarkus OIDC` library. My authentication and authorization configurations and placed in `application.properties` file and the configuration to permit the APIs looks as below

```
quarkus.http.auth.permission.public-api.paths=/restaurant/menu/{restaurantId}
quarkus.http.auth.permission.public-api.policy=permit
```

But this does not work.

Am I missing something here? Please provide some information on this.

If I replace `{restaurantId}` with `*` then it works. I do not want to add `*` here but use the path parameter.

Comment: Template variables are not supported at the configuration level, why do you prefer to use a template variable if setting `*` achieves what is required ?

Comment: @SergeyBeryozkin, I have some other APIs that have the initial path `/restaurant/menu/` and these needs `authenticated` policy. If I add `*` then those APIs will also be excluded from authentication.

Comment: Sure, in that case, consider using the annotation, `@RolesAllowed`, that will help you fine tune by putting it exactly on those JAX-RS methods where necessary